# Are there different between origin model and Model(origin model's input, origin model's output)?

Tags: python, keras

I would like to use middle layers output in the loss function, so I use

```
dis_loss = Model(input=dis_model.get_input_at(0), output=dis_model.get_output_at(-1))
func_x = dis_loss(y_true)
func_x = dis_loss(y_pred)
```

Then, I got an error message as following.

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_layer_1:0", shape=(?, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "input_layer". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

I had checked the name of `dis_model.get_input_at(0)`, and `dis_model.layer[0].input` and they are same.
first layer's name of `dis_model.summary()` is also same.

However I try to directly use `dis_loss = dis_model`, and then the model compiled successfully. Are the two models different? Input and output are from the same model, shouldn't they connect?

Answer (score 0):

2 input layers would cause 2 output layers, so

```
dis_loss = Model(input=dis_model.get_input_at(0), output=dis_model.get_output_at(-1))
```

has to be revised as

```
dis_loss = Model(input=dis_model.get_input_at(0), output=dis_model.get_output_at(0))
```

When combing 2 model,

```
gen_x = gen_model.output
dis_z = dis_model(gen_x)
d_on_g = model(input=gen_x.input, output=[gen_x, dis_z])
```

it creates second output, so
`dis_model.get_output_at(0)` is `dense_1/Tanh:0` which is dis_model's output, so it connect to the dis_model's input.

`dis_model.get_output_at(1)` is `model_2/dense_1/Tanh:0` which is d_on_g's output, so it coneect to d_on_g's input which is equal to gen_model's input.